# How to S Rank Mission 48

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've literally followed tons of guides on how to S Rank Misson 48 [Extreme] Code Talker.

I've even achieve a score of over 200,000 and on other missions I've gotten S Rank with as low as 120,000.

I've tried to do everything perfectly and still no S, is there something I should be doing that I'm missing?

[image: 200,000+ perfect stealth no s rank]

Comment: What exactly does the red text say?

Comment: "Rank restricted items used, deployment/unit support" if I had used any they would be listed, "other Rank-restricting factors" if I had used any they would be listed

Comment: Apparently instead of "Sneaking Suit Grade 6" it says "other Rank-restricting factors" as the thing that was used, I can't say how annoying it is they did not update this text to be descriptive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using rank restricting items will restrict your rank to, at most, A. You won't be able to get an S rank as long as you use rank restricting items.

Comment: Omg thanks I ran through another mission using stealth camo and it says stealth camo in red text so I analyzed my loudout and apparently one of the new sneaking suit upgrades limits you to A rank /facepalm

Comment: You want a Gibbs slap?